# Lower dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ Has $n+1$ dimensional measure zero.

Tags: measure-theory

I am reading the book
[Functions of Several Variables by M Moskowitz, F Paliogiannis](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=6GZIDQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)
in which the authors proved in Corollary 4.1.25 (Page 243) that any lower dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{R^{n+1}}$ has $n+1$ dimensional measure zero.
It is the corollary of Proposition 4.1.23. I understand the proof of this theorem but cannot capture the corollary.

In the proof of that corollary they considered a function $f(x)= \lambda(x)+x_0$, where $\lambda :\mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ is a linear map and $x_0$ is a fixed vector in  $\mathbb{R^n}$.....!!!!
But we cannot add a scalar $\lambda(x)$ and vector $x_0$.
Is their anything wrong in that proof of the corollary......??

How can we proceed further to prove this corollary using the Proposition 4.1.23.
and sorry if I made a silly mistake....!!

Comment: Probably a misprint for $\lambda:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^{n+1}$.

Comment: But they indicated $\lambda$ as "Linear Functional"....Is this also missprint...??? Well...is the proof is going well with this correction.@ Lord Shark